# Hyper-V Role Installation not starting

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

When I try to install Hyper-V Role, the progress bar stays at 0 % ... it basically never starts and I can't even close the window or cancel it, unless I restart the server .

How can I find out what's causing this ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T26D.png)

Comment: Great, please if it helped mark as answer.

Comment: Well, ok, it worked with PowerShell, but this still doesn't give any clue about why it stalled when using the GUI and how to solve *that*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install with powershell:

```
Install-WindowsFeature –Name Hyper-V -ComputerName <computer_name> -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```